# Is there any way to get 2 dragon eggs on bedrock, without cheating or dupes?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Recently I was playing Minecraft with one of my friends. I was playing on my switch, I didn't know what they were playing on.
We went and beat the dragon and before that, I took the egg from a previous fight (?).
After we beat the dragon, we went to our homes. When I went and placed my egg down, I said that I was happy to have this one-of-a-kind object.
Then, my friend said, "it's not one of a kind, I have one too".
I told them **that's impossible,** and they came over and placed their egg in their house!
How could they have gotten another egg??!?  They didn't cheat it in (I got the end achievement) and they didnt dupe it (they had theirs before I took mine from the original pedestal in the end).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears your world has had some sort of glitch, as a second egg spawning after the Dragon's death is impossible. According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dragon_Egg),

> The dragon egg is a decorative block or a "trophy item", and is the
> rarest item obtainable in the game, as **it generates once and once
> only.**

Or, your friends may have duped the dragon egg and placed one for you. This is most likely the occurrence, as the egg you found from the "previous fight" simply doesn't generate in that fashion, and your friends did in fact just place an extra fake egg on the podium for you.

Comment: Apparently it does happen semi-consistently on Bedrock. When you beat the Ender Dragon twice, the Dragon Egg just duplicates. Several Redditors had that happen.